# Trying to connect two tables but unable

Tags: mysql

I've done more complex queries and I am stumped.

table:

```
STEPS (id, rank, description) 
ELEMENTS (element, element_id, year_code)
```

The tables relate by `STEPS.id = ELEMENTS.element_id where ELEMENTS.year_code = 2010`

I want to retrieve a `step`, by its `rank`, but it needs to check the element table to make sure I pull the appropriate step, because there could be two steps with the same rank, but that is where the `year_code` comes into play, there is no duplicate ranks for the same year.

So I want to view the `step`

```
 where steps.rank = 1.2.4 and elements.year_code = 2010
```

any help is appreciated

The steps table holds all the steps and the elements table keeps track of what year the step belongs to.

Comment: What's the relationship between `STEPS` and `ELEMENTS`? That is, what columns link the two tables together?

Comment: How are `elements` and `steps` linked? By element_id?

Comment: sorry about that guys, revised my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a link field, so I'm just going to use `elements.step_id` to link the fields.
Adjust the query to your field names.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM steps s
INNER JOIN elements e ON (e.steps_id = s.id)
WHERE s.rank = '1.2.4' AND e.year_code = '2010'
```

Or perhaps you meant:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM steps s
INNER JOIN elements e ON (e.steps_id = s.id)
WHERE s.rank IN ('1','2','4') AND e.year_code = '2010'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.id, s.rank, s.description
    FROM STEPS s
        INNER JOIN ELEMENTS E
            ON s.id = e.element_id
    WHERE s.rank = '1.2.4'
        AND e.year_code = 2010
```